# Creating a Nested 3D Dictionary in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to make a 3D dictionary in python

I am having issues associating the values in my lists the way that I want them.

Here is my code:

```
def nestedDictionary3D(L1, L2):
"""
Requires: L1 and L2 are lists
Modifies: Nothing
Effects:  Creates a 3D dictionary, D, with keys of each item of list L1.
          The value for each key in D is a dictionary, which
          has keys of each item of list L2 and corresponding
          values of empty dictionaries. Returns the new dictionary D.
"""
     t1 = tuple(L1)
     t2 = tuple(L2)
     D = {t1: {t2: {}}}
     return D
```

Here is the expected output and my output:

Test case input arguments:

```
['dolphin', 'panda', 'koala'], ['habitat', 'diet', 'lifespan']
```

My return value:

```
{('dolphin', 'panda', 'koala'): {('habitat', 'diet', 'lifespan'): {}}}
```

Expected return value:

```
{'dolphin': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}, 'panda': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}, 'koala': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}}
```

Test case input arguments:

```
['Ann Arbor', 'San Francisco', 'Boston'], ['restaurants', 'parks', 'hotels']
```

My return value:

```
{('Ann Arbor', 'San Francisco', 'Boston'): {('restaurants', 'parks', 'hotels'): {}}}
```

Expected return value:

```
{'San Francisco': {'hotels': {}, 'parks': {}, 'restaurants': {}}, 'Ann Arbor': {'hotels': {}, 'parks': {}, 'restaurants': {}}, 'Boston': {'hotels': {}, 'parks': {}, 'restaurants': {}}}
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Dude thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you may use nested *dict comprehension* expression as:

```
animal, property = ['dolphin', 'panda', 'koala'], ['habitat', 'diet', 'lifespan']

my_dict = {a: {p: {} for p in property}  for a in animal}
```

where `my_dict` will hold the value:

```
{'dolphin': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}, 
 'panda': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}, 
 'koala': {'diet': {}, 'habitat': {}, 'lifespan': {}}}
```

Hence, your function could be simply written as:

```
def nestedDictionary3D(L1, L2):
     return {l1: {l2: {} for l2 in L2}  for l1 in L1}
```

You do not need to type-cast the values in the `list` to `tuple`.